# PHP SQL - not working code after upload on server

Tags: php, mysql, server

Issue: I made an application without problems working on localhost where I debuged it. But when I uploaded it on server in internet (my school server) few SQL didnt work, there were no PHP error messages and i tested SQL code in phpMyAdmin(on server)  and there it worked.

Guys,can you help me solve this please?

Comment: We cannot guess the problem. Add the relevant details.

Comment: nothing is returning from database(no content on page) on server but on local host it works fine

Comment: You probably need to add proper error handling to your code that provides some information as to what has gone wrong. If you cannot provide us any specific details, then we will not be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you cannot provide any useful information about whats wrong. In this case, we need to tell PHP that for any and every problem please send it down to the client on page load. Normally in production this is precisely what you do not want to do but in this case- we need it.

Put the code below at the beginning of your index.php file, or whatever file your web server is configured to send requests to:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

So long as your web server is successfully sending requests there, something should come up on page load that will help us determine the issue.

Comment: Your code showed me error ,now I know where is the problem and I can fix it by myself, Thank you very much